# BadlyFormattedFlowExecutionKeyException in grails webflow

Tags: exception, grails, spring-webflow

I'm getting grails "BadlyFormattedFlowExecutionKeyException" exception when I change the execution param value in address bar!! Does anyone know how to handle such Exceptions?

Cheers!

Comment: Have a look at the exception's description here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/repository/BadlyFormattedFlowExecutionKeyException.html - can you please show us the code where you define the key?

Comment: I'm talking about grails, you dont define key. Grails automatically add execute param with every url while you're in webflow.

Comment: Ok, which the URL which is giving you issues? Can you paste the stacktrace or something that let us help you?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace and the code of your flow?

Comment: And what are you changing the execution param value to?

Comment: At first place my url is ..checkout/index?execution=e12s1 for example i changed it to checkout/index?execution=123 in address bar it gives error. **Exception Message: Badly formatted flow execution key '123', the expected format is 'e<executionId>s<snapshotId>' 
Caused by: Badly formatted flow execution key '123', the expected format is 'e<executionId>s<snapshotId>'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. After a lot of googling, i made a filter for each flow.
And In 'before' closure i read params.execution, if params.execution is not null i test the state with getFlowStateName function:

[Accessing flow state name from filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268603/accessing-flow-state-name-from-filter)

if is a invalid state (the function return null) i redirect to the begin of flow (redirect controller: 'xx', action: 'yy').

Best Regards!