# How to get current view state name in grails webflow plugin

Tags: grails

How can I get current view state name in grails web flow plug-in, I am trying to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763511/grails-webflow-state-name) but I can not get it to work in my app I am getting this error message

```
No such property: flowExecution for class: ni.org.petApp.AppController
```

thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Grails 2.2.4 or 2.3.8 and the grails-webflow plugin version 2.0.8.1, I was able to access the current WebFlow state via the `requestContext`:

```
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
String stateId = requestContext.currentState.id
```

When using these methods in a WebFlow your controller should look like this:

```
package webflow.requestcontext

import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContextHolder

class TestController {

    def indexFlow = {
        randomNameForStartState {
            action {
                RequestContext requestContext = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
                flow.startStateName = requestContext.currentState.id
            }
            on("success").to "showStartStateName"
        }

        showStartStateName() {
        }
    }
}
```

You could then print the start state in the `showStartStateName.gsp` via `${startStateName}`

Based on the `requestContext`, you could also resolve the `FlowExecutionContext`:

```
FlowExecutionContext flowExecutionContext = requestContext?.getFlowExecutionContext();
```

Comment: After trying

RequestContext requestContext = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();

I tried import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContextHolder with no success
String stateId = requestContext.currentState.id

i get the following error message: unable to resolve class RequestContext

Comment: Did you import the `RequestContext` as well?
My import is looking like this:  
    `import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext`  
    `import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContextHolder`  
  
Btw, which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: i am using grails 2.3.8 i tried import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext but i got this error No such property: RequestContextHolder

Comment: I just did create a new sample project using Grails 2.3.8 and the latest version of the grails-webflow plugin 2.0.8.1.  
The controller did work for me as previously described. You can compare your attempts to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/croeck/609ecce71fc54a9ba09c). If you still can't get it to import / find the matching class please submit some more information, for instance the BuildConfig and the relevant snippet of the controller.

Comment: thanks for sharing the gist it help a lot, i was able to see my error, it is working now, could you please update your answer and add the imports needed for complete the task. To all thanks for your time.